# React Jest Testing Transpilation Errors

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am starting up a testing suite for the app we are working on at my job, and I have gotten about half of our tests to pass with a .babelrc modification, but I cannot get the JSX to transpile properly and I am not sure what settings need to be changed.

I have tried adding a .babelrc to include the plugin to transform es2015 modules, but this only got half of my tests passing. Currently I am still getting error messages for the other tests.

```
{
    "env": {
        "test": {
        "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
        }
    }
}
```

Syntax error: Unexpected Token

> ```
>   9 | 
>  10 | beforeEach(() => {
>  11 |   component = render(<App />)
>     |                      ^
>  12 | })
>  13 | 
>  14 | describe('loading App', () => {
> ```